Scale UVs to have identical size in Y or X coordinate
How can I scale different UV islands so that they all have the same size in Y, for example, respecting the original proportions. Even if the texel density is different in all of the UV islands.

I don't believe there is a native way to do this without manually scaling them all to fit. I have 3 different UV manipulation addons and none of them have this exact feature built in, It could be possible to write a script for this but I'm pretty sure it would be fairly involved, not a quick twenty-liner or nothing.
